# Routes works on localhost but not on production server

Tags: php, laravel

I have a fresh installation of Laravel. It works perfectly fine on my local machine. But on the server the routes doesn't work correctly.

Here's how the URL looks like on my localhost:

```
localhost/articles/14
```

But when I try the same URL on my production server it doesn't work. But it does work if I type the URL like this:

```
mydomain.com/index.php/articles/14
```

So, with the index.php in between it works fine. And the index route works without a problem. So it seems like some kind of redirect issue.

Here's how my .htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried adding RewriteBase /mypath/ to the .htaccess without luck.

I have searched on Google and tried some suggestion without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your server.

Also, `.htaccess` may be disabled on your server for security reasons.
Try putting your `mod_rewrite` on your `<VirtualHost>` or `<Directory>` section.

Comment: I have double checked, mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Oh... the .htaccess file doesn't work... thats weird since I have other sites on the same server where the .htaccess is working.

Comment: Check the <Directory> section, you might have an 'AllowOverride None' there

Comment: I checked for AllowOverride and added it to my .htaccess file but it didnt work. BUT, i found the AllowOverride on several places since I use Virtual Host for my websites. So adding AllowOverride All on all configs did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Needed to add the allow override section to my vhost, thanks =]